# Hibernate and MariaDB only store timestamps to second precision?

Tags: hibernate, date, mariadb

I am trying to store java Dates in a MariaDB using Hibernate. It appears that distinct Dates are treated as identical. For example: `new Date(1518458441039)` and `new Date(1518458441102)` are clearly different dates but both cannot be stored in a field declared as unique:

```
11:09:59.540 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - (conn=502) Duplicate entry '2018-02-12 14:00:41' for key 'UK_plwo79yqbhw7h0yuxbrg5ru7q'
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
        at aero.navblue.ingest.MainClass$1.cacheMiss(MainClass.java:134)
        at aero.navblue.ingest.MainClass$1.cacheMiss(MainClass.java:122)
        at aero.navblue.CacheMap.get(CacheMap.java:13)
        at aero.navblue.ingest.MainClass.insertTimestamps(MainClass.java:144)
        at aero.navblue.ingest.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:73)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2909)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: (conn=502) Duplicate entry '2018-02-12 14:00:41' for key 'UK_plwo79yqbhw7h0yuxbrg5ru7q'
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:171)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:216)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeUpdate(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry '2018-02-12 14:00:41' for key 'UK_plwo79yqbhw7h0yuxbrg5ru7q'
Query is: insert into adsb_position_timestamp (create_date, create_user, modify_date, modify_user, position_received_time) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters [<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,'2018-02-12 14:00:41.102']
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.LogQueryTool.exceptionWithQuery(LogQueryTool.java:153)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:254)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209)
        ... 26 more
```

Then field is declared as:

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "position_received_time", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 19, updatable = false )
public Date getPositionReceivedTime() {
    return this.positionReceivedTime;
}
```

Comment: Possibly, but you are referring to a six year old question whose most upvoted answer is incorrect. "The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision." from the referenced javadoc...

Comment: You are right so I researched some time and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the DB with hibernate you can use `columnDefinition="DATETIME(3)"` to enable fraction support.

```
@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME(3)", name = "position_received_time", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 19, updatable = false )
public Date getPositionReceivedTime() {
    return this.positionReceivedTime;
}
```

Otherwise for MariaDB you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
  col_microsec DATETIME(6),
  col_millisec TIME(3)
);
```

For reference you can read: [microseconds-in-mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/microseconds-in-mariadb/).